# Centering Bootstrap5 buttons on mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am currently working on a web application and I am trying to figure out how to center two bootstrap buttons side-by-side. It works on mobile, but when I try to inspect the page and view it on a mobile device, they go on separate lines and center (one on top of the other). How can I fix this so that on mobile, they appear side-by-side like on the computer? Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 text-center">
                <a href="#" style="font-size: 18px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mb-3" role="button">Button 1</a>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 text-center">
                <a href="#" style="font-size: 18px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mb-3" role="button">Button 2</a>
            </div>
        </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this. Remove the breakpoints from your columns and make them occupy half the space no matter what screen size you are using:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-6 text-center">
      <a href="#" style="font-size: 18px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mb-3" role="button">Button 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 text-center">
      <a href="#" style="font-size: 18px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mb-3" role="button">Button 2</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might look more cleaner

```
<div class="col-xl-12" style="display:flex">
<div class="btns" style="margin:auto">
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="">Button1 </a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="">Button2 </a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```